# How to resample large dataframe with different functions, using a key?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I have a large time-series set of data with over 200 recorded values (columns). Some values need to be averaged and some need to be summed, and I have a list that determines which is which. I need help figuring out how to feed that list into the how= function of resample.

Example data:

```
"Timestamp","TZ","TAO (degF)","RHO (%)","WS (mph)","WD (deg)","RAIN (mm)","OAP (hPa)","INSOL (W/m2)","HAIL (hits/cm2)"......."
2014/04/01 01:01:01.005,n,45.3,88.2,0,0.6,0.339,1.0108,-0.270342,0,68.147808,40.91662,68.15884,40.672356,66.55452,......
2014/04/01 01:02:01.027,n,45.3,88,0,3.4,0.339,1.0108,-0.124948,0,68.216736,40.929836,68.15884,40.656932,66.560072,.......
2014/04/01 01:03:01.050,n,45.3,88,0,1.7,0.34,1.0108,-0.145394,0,68.156064,40.890184,68.103736,40.68332,66.557296,......
```

The best I can come up with is concatenating the list into a string to pass into the how=function, but the concatenation of strings makes the function SeriesGroupBy error out.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(parsedatafile, parse_dates = True, date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f') , index_col=0)

while i < len(recordname):
      if recordhow[i]=="Y":
        #parseavgsum[i]="sum"
        recordhow[i]=str(recordname[i])+str(": sum")
      else:
        recordhow[i]=str(recordname[i])+str(": mean")
        #parseavgsum[i]="mean"
      i+=1

df2=df.resample('60Min', how = recordhow)
```

Comment: I do need to sum/average across all the rows. I'm taking 1 minute data and condensing to hourly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass `how` a dictionary:

```
>>> df
                             WD (deg)  RAIN (mm)
Timestamp                                       
2014-04-01 01:01:01.005000  40.916620  68.158840
2014-04-01 01:02:01.027000  40.929836  68.158840
2014-04-01 01:03:01.050000  40.890184  68.103736

[3 rows x 2 columns]
>>> what_to_do = {"WD (deg)": "mean", "RAIN (mm)": "sum"}
>>> df.resample("60Min", how=what_to_do)
                      RAIN (mm)   WD (deg)
Timestamp                                 
2014-04-01 01:00:00  204.421416  40.912213

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

I think using a `recordhow` list like you're doing is a little dangerous, because it's very easy for columns to get shuffled accidentally in which case your means and sums would be off.  It's much safer to work with column names.  But if you have `recordhow`, you could do something like:

```
>>> recordhow = ["N", "Y"]
>>> how_map = {"Y": "sum", "N": "mean"}
>>> what_to_do = dict(zip(df.columns, [how_map[x] for x in recordhow]))
>>> what_to_do
{'RAIN (mm)': 'sum', 'WD (deg)': 'mean'}
```

but again, I recommend moving away from a bare list that doesn't know what maps to what as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I see what you mean about things getting shuffled around.